# PHP Polling Sockets Eats Up CPU

Tags: php, sockets

I've written a pair of PHP socket servers that listen around for commands and respond to them. The problem is that they do so by listening in an infinite loop, and thus are eating up CPU.

So how do I do this (1) without eating up CPU; and (2) without slowing down the socket commands, particularly if I have several come in in sequence?

```
$sock = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, SOL_TCP);
socket_set_option($sock, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, 1);
socket_bind($sock, $address, $port);
socket_listen($sock);

$clients = array($sock);
$write = NULL;
$except = NULL;

while (true) {
    $read = $clients;

    if (socket_select($read, $write, $except, 0) < 1)
        continue;

    if (in_array($sock, $read)) {
        $clients[] = socket_accept($sock);
        $key = array_search($sock, $read);
        unset($read[$key]);
    }

    foreach ($read as $read_sock) {

    /* I tried putting a tiny sleep here, but if I run several socket connections for the same user sequentially, they see a notable slowdown */

        $data = @socket_read($read_sock, 1024, PHP_NORMAL_READ);

        if ($data === false) {
            $key = array_search($read_sock, $clients);
            unset($clients[$key]);
            echo "client disconnected.\n";
            continue;
        }

        $data = trim($data);

        /* And this is the heart of my loop */

     }

    } // end of reading foreach
}

// close the listening socket
socket_close($sock);
```

Comment: Use a reasonable timeout on the select. But when a socket is available for reading you should try to read as much data as possible from it. Otherwise when you get back to the select call it will return immediately since there is still data available to read. PHP_NORMAL_READ will also stop at a newline and leave unread data that will cause the same inefficiency.

Comment: So I think you're suggesting adding a value to the fourth variable in the socket_select statement? What would be reasonable? How does that help the polling? (Does the socket just sit there waiting until it gets a command, rather than the loop progresing?) As for the socket_read, I think that's likely to get all data with each grab. It's all in the form of commands, which should all be 1024 characters or less.